# Registering a Sitefinity Custom Membership provider

Tags: membership-provider, sitefinity

I am trying to implement a custom membership provider in Sitefinity, and have followed through the documentation at:  http://docs.sitefinity.com/tutorial-create-a-custom-membership-provider

When I come to register the provider in the Sitefinity backend, I get the message **The following required properties are not set: type**

I have checked, double checked and checked again the namespace and class names, and can even declare a variable as the provider type in the code-behind, yet it just won't have it.

My provider is defined thus:

```
namespace SitefinityWebApp
{
    public class WebsiteMembersProvider : MembershipDataProvider
{
    public WebsiteMembersProvider()
{
    //... etc
```

I am registering the provider in the SF backend as:

```
SitefinityWebApp.WebsiteMembersProvider, SitefinityWebApp
```

And I can go into the code behind on one of my master pages and code:

```
SitefinityWebApp.WebsiteMembersProvider MyTestProvider;
```

and indeed, the class appears in the intellisense offerings just fine.

and the project all compiles/runs fine - but SF won't let me use the custom provider!  I have also tried adding the provider manually in the securityconfig.config file - similar result.

Any idea anyone?

Answer (score 0):

I went through the tutorial to try it myself and ran into the same problem as you.

Are you sure that you're putting this

```
SitefinityWebApp.WebsiteMembersProvider, SitefinityWebApp
```

in the ProviderType field (and not the 'Global resource class ID' field, which is what I initially did)? It seems like that error message shows up if I remove the text from that field and attempt to save (and also when it can't resolve that type).

Otherwise, I'm not sure what else it could be, aside from maybe recycling the app pool.

Comment: Hi!  Thanks for response.  I'm 100% sure I've been entering the types correctly, and in the correct field.  The tutorial (and downloadable "fullcode"have a few inconsitencies with the namespaces, etc, but the fact that I can declare a variable of the type of my membership provider suggests that that part is now correct... I'll continue to liaise with SF support and will post my answer as & when I get it!